# Уникальные поля Django ORM

Tags: python, django, orm

Недавно начал изучать Django, и у меня возникла трудность с моделью. Мне нужно чтобы два поля одной модели не могли совпадать. То есть, у меня есть модель Profiles, где есть поля first_name и last_name. Я хочу чтобы пользователь не мог ввести одинаковые значения для этих двух полей.
Единственное что я нашёл это unique и unique_together, которые позволяют сделать уникальными поля разных экземпляров модели. Но никак не влияют на уникальность внутри одного экземпляра.
И у меня возникает вопрос, как такое поведение можно было бы реализовать.

Comment: как вариант переопределить метод `save()`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/#pre-save
Я бы поставил хук на событие pre_save.
тут описано как https://stackoverflow.com/a/6462188/12605749

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь. В итоге решил проблему с помощью переопределения метода clean у формы, который, как я понял, вызывается в момент вызова метода is_valid.

Answer (score 1):

Чтоб добавить ограничение на уровне БД, используйте `CheckConstraint`:

```
class Profiles(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=~models.Q(first_name=models.F("last_name")),
                name='first_and_last_names_different'),
        ]
```

Альтернативный вариант проверять перед сохранением в переопределенном методе `save` или в `pre-save` сигнале.

Вариант с методом `clean` в форме также можно использовать, нужно только понимать, что при создании объектов не через форму, такая проверка работать не будет. Так что, в дополнение к проверке в форме (это по сути проверка в UI), нужна обязательно проверка и, как минимум, в модели, а лучше на стороне БД.

Comment: У меня данный способ вызывает ошибку при миграции: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'ne' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.

Comment: Точно. исправил